# Error when trying to compile on Windows

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, runtime-error, rust

I just downloaded Rust 0.6 and tried to compile the hello world program. However, I get following error when trying to do so:

> The procedure entry point "_gxx_personality_v0" was not found in rustrt.dll.

My GCC version is 4.5.2. From what I read on the getting started page Rust is supposed to work with GCC 4.5.* on Windows. My OS is Win8 64 bit.

Comment: what command are you issuing?

Comment: Have you tried it with Rust 1.0 alpha?

Answer (score 1):

There's more information about this bug [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/7953). This was fixed when Rust [added support for mingw-w64](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/8488) in August 2013. Rust 1.0 and later versions are unaffected.